# How can i display json data in jsp using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc. My controller "Book.java" is returning a json object.
I want to display the content of json object in the form of table in jsp.
How can i do that.

The function in My Controller which is returning json object:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/book")
public class BookController {

@Autowired
BookService bookService;

@RequestMapping(value="/list",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<Book> getBookList(){
    List<Book> bookList = null;
    try{
        bookList = bookService.getBookList();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("bookList returned");
    System.out.println(bookList);
    return bookList;
}
```

The bookList is list of books having contents "bookId" and "bookName".
I want to display the content in jsp in a table. How can it be done.

I tried like this but the data wasn't displayed.

```
<table id="table1" align = center border='1.5' width='600' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1'>
<h2>Book Details</h2>
<tr>
    <th>BookId</th>
    <th>BookName</th>
<!--     <th>Item Details</th>   -->
</tr>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**My jquery call**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function madeAjaxCall(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://localhost:8080/restApp/book/list",
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType:"json",
success: function(data){ 
        if(data){
            var len = data.length;
            var txt = "";
            if(len > 0){
                for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
                    if(data[i].bookId && data[i].bookName){
                        txt += "<tr><td>"+data[i].bookId+"</td><td>"+data[i].bookName+"</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
                if(txt != ""){
                    $("#table1").append(txt).removeClass("hidden");
                }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
});


</script>
```

I tried to test the jquery call through a button

```
<button onclick="madeAjaxCall()">book list</button>
```

But the data could not be displayed.

**JSON**

```
[{
    "bookId": 1,
        "bookName": "aa",
        "chapter": [{
        "chapterId": 1,
        "chapterName": "xx",
        "book": null
    }, {
        "chapterId": 2,
        "chapterName": "yy",
        "book": null
    }]
}, {
    "bookId": 2,
        "bookName": "bb",
        "chapter": [{
        "chapterId": 4,
        "chapterName": "pp",
        "book": null
    }, {
        "chapterId": 3,
        "chapterName": "zz",
        "book": null
    }]
}, {
    "bookId": 3,
    "bookName": "cc",
        "chapter": [{
        "chapterId": 5,
        "chapterName": "qq",
        "book": null
    }, {
        "chapterId": 6,
        "chapterName": "rr",
        "book": null
    }]
}, {
    "bookId": 4,
    "bookName": "dd",
        "chapter": [{
        "chapterId": 8,
        "chapterName": "tt",
        "book": null
    }, {
        "chapterId": 7,
        "chapterName": "ss",
        "book": null
    }]
}]
```

Comment: 1) does http://localhost:8080/restApp/book/list return valid JSON 2) is this on the same origin (server and port number) 3) any errors in the console?

Comment: yes json object is being returned. i checked it

Comment: catch(Exception e) = bad practice!

Comment: Show some JSON please

Comment: [{"bookId":1,"bookName":"aa","chapter":[{"chapterId":1,"chapterName":"xx","book":null},{"chapterId":2,"chapterName":"yy","book":null}]},{"bookId":2,"bookName":"bb","chapter":[{"chapterId":4,"chapterName":"pp","book":null},{"chapterId":3,"chapterName":"zz","book":null}]},{"bookId":3,"bookName":"cc","chapter":[{"chapterId":5,"chapterName":"qq","book":null},{"chapterId":6,"chapterName":"rr","book":null}]},{"bookId":4,"bookName":"dd","chapter":[{"chapterId":8,"chapterName":"tt","book":null},{"chapterId":7,"chapterName":"ss","book":null}]}]

Comment: Once I formatted the JSON correctly I have this: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9b8fz53n/

Answer (score 2):

First you need to change your ajax call to be a 'GET' request.

This:

```
 type: "POST",
```

Needs to be this:

```
type: "GET",
```

You also need to set the content type to json with:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

**Update**

The following line will error:

```
 if(data[i].bookId && data[i].bookName){
```

I'm guessing you may want that to be something like:

```
 if(data[i].bookId != null && data[i].bookName != null){
```

Comment: @bablu Did you also set the contentType? See my other update. Post the error you are receiving too. It will be easier for people to resolve.

Comment: yup, i did set the contentType to contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",

Answer (score 0):

It seems the json output you posted is an array, not an object (starts with [, not {). You could use JSONObject class to output proper json object.